Fail to install cmdstanr in remote machine
I am trying to install cmdstanr in a remote linux machine. I have successfully managed to install cmdstan using conda.
However when I try to install cmdstan with in a R shell (install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c('https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev', getOption("repos"))). I get the following error.
Any clue how to fix this ?
Installing package into ‘/hpc/home/mou.roy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) 
also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘data.table’, ‘processx’ 
 
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ps_1.7.7.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 128844 bytes (125 KB) 
================================================== 
downloaded 125 KB 
 
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/data.table_1.16.0.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5302544 bytes (5.1 MB) 
================================================== 
downloaded 5.1 MB 
 
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/processx_3.8.4.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 163983 bytes (160 KB) 
================================================== 
downloaded 160 KB 
 
trying URL 'https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/cmdstanr_0.8.1.tar.gz' 
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 863018 bytes (842 KB) 
================================================== 
downloaded 842 KB 
 
* installing *source* package ‘ps’ ... 
** package ‘ps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked 
** using staged installation 
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual' 
* removing ‘/hpc/home/mou.roy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ps’ 
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ... 
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked 
** using staged installation 
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual' 
* removing ‘/hpc/home/mou.roy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/data.table’ 
ERROR: dependency ‘ps’ is not available for package ‘processx’ 
* removing ‘/hpc/home/mou.roy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/processx’ 
ERROR: dependencies ‘data.table’, ‘processx’ are not available for package ‘cmdstanr’ 
* removing ‘/hpc/home/mou.roy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/cmdstanr’ 
 
The downloaded source packages are in 
‘/tmp/Rtmp4GuBG4/downloaded_packages’ 
Warning messages: 
1: In install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev",  : 
  installation of package ‘ps’ had non-zero exit status 
2: In install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev",  : 
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status 
3: In install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev",  : 
  installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status 
4: In install.packages("cmdstanr", repos = c("https://stan-dev.r-universe.dev",  : 
  installation of package ‘cmdstanr’ had non-zero exit status 


Why not use the Conda version? I.e., conda install r-cmdstanr assuming conda-forge channel is prioritized. It is important to understand that the reproducibility of Conda is immediately compromised once users do install.packages. As such, I generally recommend all Conda R users avoid it. This is especially complicated in cases where packages need compilation, and even more so for Stan, which actually compiles at runtime.
